# How to localize static content in database with Django

Tags: python, django, localization

My app has tables for languages and countries (actually [django-countries](http://code.google.com/p/django-countries/) at the moment, but open for suggestions). The tables are populated when I initialize the database and remain static after that.

What would be the ideal localization mechanism for the contents of these tables, so that I can show the country and language names to users in their chosen site language?

I'm aware of projects like django-multilingual and transdb, but IMO they are more suitable for dynamic content, i.e. stuff that's supposed to be modified.

Please englighten me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but why just not use [un]gettext, i.e. `{% trans lang_from_db %}` and `_(lang_from_db)`?

Alternatively, hardcode language names translated in their own language into database, e.g "English", "Svenska", "Suomi", etc.